# Packaging MongoDB with packager.py

Tags: mongodb, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Trying to package my custom built MongoDB 2.6.6 (with SSL), I'm using the packager.py script from buildscript/ in the sources I got from [www.mongodb.org](http://www.mongodb.org).

I've changed it in a few places, based on [this](http://dougchang333.blogspot.co.il/2012/10/mongodb-220-rpm-build-instructions.html) and on errors I've had because of file locations.

I've come along way, but now the error I'm getting is from within `rpmbuild`:

```
error: File not found: /tmp/tmp7vZvNP/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mongodb-org-2.6.6-1.%{_arch}/usr/bin/mongod
```

Put aside the fact I searched and couldn't find where the `%{_arch}` thing came from, the `mongod` binary file exists in `/tmp/tmp7vZvNP/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mongodb-org-2.6.6-1.%\{_arch\}/usr/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.6/bin/`

Where is {_bindir} defined for the spec file?
Any other idea what's the next thing I should be pursuing?

Comment: `%{_bindir}` is a default RPM macro. Run `rpm -E '%{_bindir}'` to see the default value. (It may be over-written in your spec or macros file but I think that's unlikely.) `%{_arch}` is odd as that shouldn't be there literally that should have been expanded to an arch value (`i386`, `x86_64`, etc.) by rpm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading @Etan Reisner's comment, I did the following:
Changed `write_rpm_macros_file` to look like this:

```
def write_rpm_macros_file(path, topdir, arch):
    f=open(path, 'w')
    try:
        f.write("%%_topdir  %s\n" % topdir)
        f.write("%%_arch    %s\n" % arch)
        f.write("%%_bindir  %s" % "/usr/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.6/bin/")
    finally:
        f.close()
```

And now I have an RPM built correctly.

**Edit:
I changed the binaries tar.gz file and now the %_bindir macro is not needed...**

Comment: That's an awfully specific path to include there but ok. There should be a way for this to work more correctly I would hope.

Comment: You seem to be right. That's the structure of my binaries tar that required this addition. I just changed the structure of the binaries file, and now this awful macro is unnecessary.